# How to pass a parameter including "&" using GET method?

Tags: php, get

In my website, I am passing the user input to a new page using get method. And I am having troubles when the user enters something with `&`. I am reading two inputs from user. Assume the user entered `xxxyyzz` for `$_GET['input1']` and `aaa&bbb` for `$_GET['input2']`. Here is the page the user is directed to:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/?input1=xxxyyzz&input2=aaa&bbb
```

In the directed page, I am getting the inputs using this code:

```
$input1 = $_GET['input1'];
$input2 = $_GET['input2'];
```

Obviously `$input2` is not populated properly when the user enters an input with something `&`.

Is there any simple way to handle this other than replacing all `&`s with another string?

Comment: URL encoding? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: try `http://www.mywebsite.com/?input1=xxxyyzz&input2=aaa%26bbb`

Comment: @KristerAndersson yep. It looks like I will need to replace & with %26. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3608791/1164491